# Prefixing widget_posts_args Hook

Tags: hooks

I am working on a theme that I am trying to submit to wordpress.org. I tested the code with theme sniffer plugin and I have the following error:

```
Hook names invoked by a theme/plugin should start with the theme/plugin prefix. 
Found: "widget_posts_args".
```

My code is the following:

```
    $nasio_r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
        'posts_per_page'      => 3,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    ) ) );
```

How should I add the prefix without breaking the code?

Comment: What’s the context of this code. Why are you using the widget_posts_args filter to begin with?

Comment: Here is the link to the whole code. I am extending the recent posts widget to add post thumbnail: https://www.pastiebin.com/5e2042c05fbe2

Comment: In that specific context it might be appropriate to use that filter like that. A code sniffer can't know that, though, so you will just need to make it clear to the reviewer what it is you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, @JacobPeattie, I will let the reviewer know.